# Decode None encoding byte in Python

Tags: python

I have this byte variable and I don't know how can I decode in utf-8. I tryied with `.decode('utf-8')` and I got this answer: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 0: invalid start byte`

I'm scraping facebook requests with seleniumwire. The requests is the blue one:
[image]

The response should be:
[image]

```
b'\x07e.\x00d\xda\xdb|\xfe\xbf~\xcfp\xdf\xdbi\x13\x12\xb2yW\x8dZ\xb5.[\xb5\xcbu\x18L0A\t\xa4@\xd4\xb4\xe3\xff\xed\xe7\xe7\xf1\xeb\xd6\xd8u\xa5\x08]Y\xe1_\x85\xa3\xe3\xef\xcc\x9ds\x1a\x12\xc9\xfe\x14\xb3\x80\x90;w\xee{\x13^@\xca/\xbd\x12\xb10\x15\x86\x92\x05>\xbeh\\\xe5\xa7\x82p\xf5u\x15\xba\xc2w\x19\xce\xfe9\xb1\xed\xc9\x97\x16IB\x8c\x942y[\'\xa5\xff\xfc\xcf_\xff\xfa\xbf\x7f\xfd\x055m\x85\xa29\xe8\xbc\xccc@\xe7\x178k\xd3\xff\xaft\x10v\xfd0\x8c1N\xe2\xc8\xf7\x12\xd7i\x0c\xd3\x0er]\xd7\x0b\xa2\x08\xc5\x91\x1b\xa3\xd0\xf9\'!\xd9\xc9\x12\xf2\xe5\x1e\xfe\xde\xfd\xdco\xc4M\x94\xa3\xcf\xe5f\xfaQ&\xbb\xde\xf2\xfb\xaa\x11\x92\x8a\xa4OI,/y7O\x97[\xb1i\xfd\xbbU\xcb\xcf;\x1a/\xdc\xe3\xb7\x1c&\x1eVO\xcao\x8f\xc1\x9e\x9d\xdb\xcd\xe2Vo\xb2\xe0%\xca\xfd\x1d\xbf\x95\x15\n\xbd}\xe3\x9d\xe9w\xfb\xd9\x98i\xdd\xdd\xb5\xd1\x08\xb9q\x10l\xde\x1bQ\xad\xd2\x8b\x08\xfaK\x89\x87w\x94\xc5j0\x9d\xbf\xb2z\xe5\x8e\xb7f\x86\xf08;\xb9\xbd\xe1H\xd3\xb8\x9a\xb4\x8b-\x1b\xac^\xeb1\x9d~\x0fp \xb7\xdd\x99\xde_\xcf\xde|\x97<q\xb2\xe0}v\xff.\xfe\x8b\x10+\t\xf9\xfb\xbf\x1b\xd7\xf5\x02?\xfdw\xe3\xba^\xf0}\xb1\xbct\xf9\xb4\x06\x9d_\xc0\xb4V\x1atNT\x18\x06\xc1\x1d\x8f=u\xd0\xf9\x05\xb6\xad\x19\xe8\x00\xad\x1a\xcb\xc8\x0c\xfeE\x01\x04\xec^+m\x89\xfc\xb9\xd0\xcc*=\xee\x83\x0e@\xae\xeb\x86\xae\xeb\x06\x01\n]\x1c\x01\x08\xb4Rv\xc7\xd9-o\x97\x10\xe2\xfa\x11\x0c\xe8|\xfd\x02B\xceF\x83\x0eXju\xe2\x82\xa5\xaabv\x81\xfe)w\xdbP\xb1g\xdaZ)\xfb|Ge\xb7\x1ax\xc0rS\x99\xb4\xba\xbd]\x80[\xc0\xe3\x80\x184\xbf\xd6A\xe7s\x12\xa8\xb5\xaa1\x06\x8e\xda\xe9\xb8\x0f:_\x93 h\x0c\xa3\x05\xc7W- \xb8rv\xdbM\xa9\xf48\x10\x08*s.\x8b-\xb1\xc7\xc9F\x88\xcdt\xf1\xfb\xd1,\x1f\xf7\xdfny@\x80\xd8\xa0%\xe0\xd2\xe4\x9c\x1eo\xf8\x01\x81\xd54cK%x\xd6\x82\x0e\xc8T\xc5\xecs\x9d\n\xcf\x19A\xd3d\xf3\xac\x00\x82\x8aY\xca\x13o\x93[\xc1@\x07,LF\xf5\x9f\x19\xcb\xb9\xa4\x00\x82[\x89\x18\xa6t\x0b+y\n\x00\xbe\x1a\x9b\x95\xf4(\x18\xe8X\xdd0\x08,\xaf\xd8\xa6f\xd2\xa6J\x9ex\x01:\xbf\xa0\xa4\xa6\xa5\xa7"\x86\x19\xc3\x95$</4\xaa\xa4\x86\x90/\xcbv(2\xb4\xe0\xb6}emUjs\x8apl\xd7/\xe8\xec\n\xf0p#\xe6\xa1\xd2\x02\x08\xee\xfdn\x11t\x00^\xa62\xa8\x9e\x96\xdb\xbe\xd6\xaa.\x83]^|@pfW\xa8V\xa0T-B\xca\xee\x1f\x0f\x08Jen\xcez\x80I.\x9e6\xa3RI\x9eQ\xf1\xa6\x85\xc8)\xe5\xf7\x04\x15\xb5YI\xb8<\xa9~J\xf2~\x9f5cK\xaaiE\x04rOw\x81\x9d\xaa\x01\xab2\x14@\xaeP\x198"e\x01z\x05B?\x80-m\xdc5{[\x90\xb9\x01x\xbc_ XA\xb3vN+\x9e*\x1e p441\xc7\xd6\xd4\x96Bi\x9dBh$\x8c\xc0\xeb\xb9>\tv\x91\x00\xaa-\x92\xb8v\x94z\x9f\x95\x12\xba\x8e\xb3%\xe8x\r\x99\xdf\xceK=\xfc\x85\xec/\xb5_\xe7\xc3\x01\x8f\xc3\xe3\x01\x81\xa3LFuN\xaf<\x7f\xaeT\xe2\x7f>\x9a_\x99V\xcf\xc8\x99\xe8k\x9c\x88\xc7\xdb\xf2\x8a\t.\xd9\x94\x9b\xc2\r\xae/\x8eb\xabh\xac\xed\x94([\xab\x8d\xb0\xae\x86\x1cDr!\x1a\xd2E\x97\xf6k\x0c\xd3;*\xb9mA\x070a\x19pJx\xbd\x14ZsF@\x990\x1eE\xda\x92\xf7\xdf\xf8,\xb8\xb1\xceD\xef\xf2\x1b\xb4\xdd\x8b\xe8\x82\x94\xf2\xe4&\xc8Y+\x92b\xfdg\xce\xc73\xd2\xbb\xba\xf6\xa6\xda&Y\xae\xe4\xd8\xc8_(\x13\xd7\r\x82\xc0\x8b\xc2$\xc4a\x0c\x9c\x8b\x06\xafH\x13\x03\xc6\x16\xf4\xea\x11\x90\xda\x95iL\xfd^r\x0f\x87\xaf\xa2\x07x,\x04\xe6\x02\xc0\\W\xcen\xd4l9\xf5\xa3R\xc6\xb2\x9c\xd0\xc6*\xa2j&w\xb6 \xb52\x96\xf8F\x07X\xaa\x0b\xb6Q\xe5d/E\xcdN\x99v\xc3(\xd0\xf1\xa1z\x04\xc9\x14~\xbe=\x1c$\x8e\xef\xeaj\x1c)\xdb#j&\xdd\xe2\xbbV\xda\xa7=\x03\xc6\x9eS!p\x93od\xd7\xb5Q4\x93\ng?\xcc3\xfd;+\x00\xe0\xe9\xcd)\xad\xa78\x0e;\x10r\x013y\xe0\x8bVMm\xec\x9c\x99&\xf5\xb9\xc9\x1a\x9f\x85\x8f\x82J\x82=u\xa4\r\x90\xd0\xce\xe8\x13c\xf9A\xce\xf5<\x08\x9e\xf8\x9d\xb9SUUL\xda\x83\x9bYx\xa8\xcd}\x94\xe4)J\xc5\x8d\xddX\xa5\xb9D\xe3\xcc\x82\x0c\x99jQF\x94/}^\x05\x96\xdaj\x9a]\xb8,\x8c\x97j\x89\xbb\xc5\x00\xb5E\xe4u6\x9cRC\xe2h\x02&\xaeC\xa6?mRU\xd5\x9a\xfei\xff\\\x99\xb4\xf4\xcf\xff\xf4\x1a&\x95\xf9\xd3\xe5\x9a\x99\xff=\x86\xea\xd1oT\xf0\x19\xf7\xb3\x01\xe25b\x9fDt\xcd\xe6\xbc\x13\xe1o\t\x0793\xf5\x8b\xd9S\xe2\r\x9e@=?D\xb1\x8fB\xcfs\x04q=N\x8a\xdd8\x9e+\x1d\x02t\xd1jZ\xa5r*l\x11y\xd2\x81\x9e\x86\xd4LWTpy\x91Q\xce\xaf\xba\x03\x9a\xd5\xa2%\r\x8a\xc9l=~\xc8,\xf1I\xc8C\xc7\x01\x17\xee\x1eH\xa6\xaaZ\x19\xa6\x89qc)\xa9\x1bS\x92\x9a\x16\x87\x9c\x93W\xce\xd5\xd5\xcc\xad\xb4\xe5\xb2 \x0b\x93"\xbc\xd4\x9b+\xb2{\x8d\x85\x02\x81\x82\xcbtm\x15\xed\xecY\xe8\xf9\xf6\xaf\xac\x8e\x88\xc4\xac\x8b\xdcm\xd3mb\xff@\xbb\x16!\xaeO\x04A\xa6\x98\xce\xf8Q0i\xbb\xa3\xa0\xb7XL\xc1\x83\x15|\x13\xa2\xae:\xfc\xb7\xb7\x01\xcf\x81\xc7\xe5`D\xdf\x80\n\xb8\xd87\x05\x8c\x08\xf8\xaeO ?\xfexB\xb7(\xba:\x85\xd2\x1ba\x00\xc1\xccC\xa4\xbd\x93\x85\xd5\x07\xde!\xfc+\xe8\xf02\xa8"\xdfu)>\xea\tz\tm\x9b_\x1c\xd9aF\xba\x98\xa7A\xac\xcf\x93>\x9c\xdf\x7f^9\xbb=\x9c\xdf\x7fZ\x13\x1d\x15o\xf9\x80\xc0h2Gttit\xfd\xdf\x83\xf2\xc9\xc5\xe5\xde\xa7\xc1\xc0\xd2\xc8\x8d\xbd\xc0\x07\x9d\xdf\xc0\xb1R\x93\xbf\x8a\x92\x9a\x12t@w\x1bH\\\xf6\xa6\xfe\xc7v&W{\xeb^\\\xf0\x80 I\xc2\x04\xbb%5]\xcc\xf5\xb9#U\x7f4\x83\x97\xd67\xe7\x17D\xefl\x96\xee|\xe4y8\xf4\xa3\x8f\x17\x9c\xacE\xb3\xbf7\xb7~\xe5\xbf\xff\xc4\xeb8m$\xf4\xfd6YH\x9f\xf3x\xe3?\xfb\xa2O\x87\xab&\xaf\xe8\xad\x9b\xee|\x14\xbb\x08\xbb\xf1\xe5y\x87\xbd2\x8d\x06\xb7\xee\xfei\xc3\xa3\xde\x08\xa7;\x1d\xc78\xf0\x83\xeb\xf3^\x86\x93\xcf\xea\xa6\xe7\xe5(\xc5d\x9c\xa9t\x8d\x868\x08p\xf8\xfc\x98\x9az\xb3\xf2n\xac\xb79\xef\x9e\xfc\xeb[\xba\x86\xa3\xc4\x8fc\xfc\x82\xa1\xf5\xcf\x9f\xdf<\xfe\xbcm\xb1\xc0IJ\xd1\xc3w\x93$N\xfa\xef9/\xa2\xf5\xa6\x9b\xcf\x1d\xe9\xbf\xbe\xac\xf9\xa5Hw.J\x02\xe4F\x1e\xa4\xcf\x1f\xd1\xc1\xf5g\x81\x16dD\xce\xf1(P\x97\xa0[\xe1\x9b1\xcel(\nc\x1c\x12W\x03\x0c\x9cwKy\x14<V4\x9a\xcc6\x879o\x8b\xf88\x8c\x90\xef\xc1\xf8\xeb\xec\xdcX&\xb3\x96R\x15\xd7<\x8b> \xd0Fg3ZQ\xebYz;\x17j|$\xe3b\x9c\r\x80\xc0\xe8\x0ct@imm:\x8e\xf3DM}\xed\xb3\xe7\xfb\xfd\xf9t\xccr\xf9,\x99u\xb4\xd1\xd9s]\xd6\xce\xd5w\xda7G;\xab\xb7Mw\xca\x87\x93|\xad\x9f\xcf\xe6\x9fDf\xe4\xfew\xb4\xe7\'\xd9o+jS\x00A\r:\xa0\xe3!\xf0\x80 3\xbaC|\xe2\x92h\x05:\xbf\xc0\xb6\xf5T\x86\x82\xd1\x00|\xc3\x0e\x82\xc8\xc5\xd0\x87^\x99\xab\x83H\x8f\xd2\xcf@\x1eq\xdd\r=\x88>\x03\xf9\xa4\x94\x9fk\x10A\x0c\x91\x0b=\x0c\x11N r]\x18\xc1\x04"\x18\xc3\x10z!\xf4a\x10\xc2$\x86\x01D\x1e\x7f\xc7\xcf\x9f\xf7w\xbb\xcf\x82\xb2?\xe8<\x94C\xec\xb4\xda\x11\x0e3d\xb0q\x14\xdd\xb3\xba\xaaP\x95\r\x88\x9cC!nq\xec\x1f\xcd\xfc\xbe\x0c\xe1HL\x8e\x1ev\xdaA\'\x8cFo\xf5b\'\xf7?o\xf3\x94\xf4z.\x86\x93\xf1\xadn\xd1\xcb\xd9\xef\xb4=G;h\x7f[L^t}%\xef\x8d\x9f8\xe3\x00< \x18\x9d>\x12|[\xbd\x9f\xed\x81\xa3\x9d\xf1\xcb\x8a\xee\xee\xc1p\x91.R2P\xa3\xf1K\x9b\xa0\x9a\xed?_J\xf8\xbc\xd8a\xa7=\xf6}\xbb\xef\\\xdc\xf5\x16\xab\\\xce\xa3\xb4|\x8cX:\x18&\x1f\xa7\xf7\x1d\xc0\xd0\x85(\x86(\x8a \xf2\xa1\xefB\x84}?\x80\x08!\x88\x12\x88\xe6\x80\xc4o\xfe1\x8a\xd6\x97\x92\x8e%|\x7f\xf3\xb1\xd3\x9e\xf1i\xf7\x0b\xe6\xdb\xf5V7\xc5U\xa4\xf5Q\x10\xc9g\xa0\x80\xf0\xea\xf5x\x10E\xd0\x8b\xa0\x17@\xcf\x83\xc8\x0b\xa1g@\xe3\xf8\x96\x1d\xa3\xf9\xb2E!\xb1:\xaf\xb0\xd3\xde:!\x9c\x08\x9cN\x07\xabnuK\xc9H\x0c\xaf\x7f\xad\t\xdf\xb9\xbd\x9e\xfdN\x9b;\xda\xb9\xec?v\xf3\xedk0\x9b&\x8d\xaf\xef\xc5.\xed\xf64$r\xa3\xd7\x92\xde\'~\x0eC.\xfem\xbe\xaf\x8f/\xe1\xd1\xd4\xfdE\xa2m&\xd8i\xfb\x1d\x10\xbe\xdco\x91Z\xc4?5C\xe4|O\xc0\xae\x7fN=o\x16\xaesN8m\xe2h\'\xedN\x16+\xa6\x82\xd1\xbe+W\xf0\x02\xb1\n\x1a\x91"+$\x9e$}@\xe8\x070I \x8aa\x04=\x17"\xec\xc5\x18z^\x00\x91\x0f=_\xcc\xca\x03\x1e\x0f\x14\x93\xf7;\xfd\xa4\xa5\x02%\xe4G-\xefAk\xd8\xcd\xa8\xff\xe3\x8c\x9b\xfc\x91\x13\xeelg\x8ev\xbe\x9f\xc6/\xa3\xf52N\x86\xbb\xb4?BQ\x84\x11\x0cFI\xfcsO.D0\x84>\xc4\xec\xa6\x8b\x06;\x92\xec\x03\x14D\xeb\xde\xfb\x9d\x8e\'sRD\xcd\x97\x89\xfb\xcf\x15vZ\xdc\xee\xdd!\xd5\xcb\x8f{\xd5\xd7,\xe5Qdic\xd9\xed\x96\x1fc\xad)\x13\xdf\xd2\x08;m\xd3\t\xe9\xf9\xe7m`_^\x17\x97\x97\xb4>\x8acj\x07\xcb\x08\x1a\xde\x86\xbdX\xea\x8b\xc8u\xc5}\x0c\xf6\xdc\xe0\x8b\xeb\x82\xcd\xcb\tS\xbb\xb9\xd0\xfd8\x11\x82\x07\x04\x9b\xfe\x80\x9d\x96\xbd~H,\xf7\x04;m\xda\xee\x93\xc5d\xf4i\x86="\xc3\x94\x0b\xdcy\x1e\xf1;\x0f\xbb\x8b\xd9^\xf0\xc2\xb9\xe1\xb4\xc6\xd1Nv\xcb\xaeu\xea\xef\xb3\xba\xd7x\x05\xd6\r\xc1\x18\xb9\xf3dDu\xa08R\xbb\x18B\xacZ\xbb\x17\x1fo\x9fx\xb6\xbeD\r\xff\x0f\xe8\xc2\x11\x8e\x0b3\xad\x8cq\xfc\xb3u\xb9\x1b\ti\xeb\xe7\xcc r+\xc2\xc1<\x99\xf8\xcdN\xf3K\x92E\xb2tn8\xed\xca\xd1N\xbe\x98\xf6%z\xa9?\xfaCK5\x18\'\x93\xed\xe4\xb2[\r\xcb|6\xde\t\xb4\xd9\x0c\xf6\xf1\x11\xcd\xd1$U\xf82\x13\xe8DL\x90\xf3C\x8f\xffu\x06.\xf4\xdc\x10\xc6\x11\x0c}\x18F0\xc4\x10\xb9\x9e\x8a}\x1d\xc8\x87(\x88!\xc6.D\x18&1\x8cg\x1d\xc5\xf3e:\xd9\xb6xD\xd1\xb3\xfd\xc7\xd1Nl\xd9u\xd7>\x8dG\x9e\x9bV\xc0>G\x06*\x88\xfe\xff\xb1(\x82\x9eE\x19\xeab\xab\x12\xbf\xb7\xfez\xfe\x9a\xbf\xb0@\t\x7f\xfa0\xd8i+\xbf\xb5\x03.\xeb\xd5t\x1b\x0b\xde\x0b|\xbd\xab\x04a\xa0\x92\x9c\x16\xdc8\xec\xc0\xd0\x85q\xe4\xbb\xa0\xdfb\x8d\xc5b\xc8TR\xa2\x8d\x1f{n8m\xe5h\xe7D_?\xeec\xf3:\xf9DH]\to\x1e\'\xe9\xc0r\xf1\xc4\x83I\x02=7v\xbdS\x11\x83\x81G\xae\xfc\x84\x92\xd0\x87~\x08}\xc4\x89\xf90b\xc0\x92\x08A\x84a\x1c\xfa\x1cT!m\xee\x99\x8c\xdd\xe5./\xf8y\x9d\x1e\xf4\\\xe8{0@\x10c\x88\x02\xe8G\x10y\xf3\xe6\xe2\xf7\x19|\xf3\xe3\xf7\x96p%\xbc\xb7\r\xb1\xd3\xee\x072\xed.\xda\xcd\xeb\r\xffL\xb2`\x95V\xf0\x12\'6\xd8\x85\xac\xfd|\x005\xac\xe6\nV\xd1.\x97\xc4?1\x0c\xaa\xf7y\xf8\xca\xe7j,\xda\xee\xed\xf0}\xb3]\x87U\xd1\xf7S\xca3\x13qT\xdf\xf8\xff\xc7\xbb\x84\x9e\x89\xdb{\x0f;\xed\xa4\xdd\xd9\xe7\xf1<:}\xc7\xb8\xea\xa7\x15\xfcH\xc0\x02\t2\xfaT\xcc45ta\xe8s#\xf2\'\xd5\x82\x9a\x05S\xfe;\xb5\x82\x81*2xWz\'\x1d0^\x0e\xa1!\x9a\x0e\xcd\xeb8\x945\xd94\xdc\xa9\x95*"\x96\xf9\xe2\x12\x08\nm\xe5\xc3\x03Nq\xc3\xca0\nf0\xda\xb9G\\\xb7\xda\xb2\xf5iU\x1c\x14\x10<\x9a\xed\x00\x81\xceO\xeb\x03\xec\xa4\x02\x9d/\x90\x16aVSn\xca\xc1\xd4J\xbc\xab\xb5\xfa\xd01\xd3\x90.x\xe6\x97<\xb3\x8df\x83\x9c\xdb^c\xad\x92\x05T]\xc9\xee\xb1\xf4\xd5\xe8\xd1Jg\xe9q\xb5e\xf7\xf3U7\x87r\xd9\xf2\xf7\x94\xaa+\xd3\xcbRY\xd5*T5\xc7Te\x17\x96\x97;\xc9\x1e\xcd\x0b\xb6\xe7\xb6\\\xaaZ]\xb1q\xa2\n\xf5/\xd9\xd7\xb4(\xe8Q\xb0\x9a\xf3\x07HD\x8c\x94\x91x\x15\x89\x1a\x918\x0e\x89\xac\x18\x9e\x83\x00\xc7\xfe\x87\x07\x04\x9a\xea\xcf\xd7\x134g\xebFJ\xa6S\xc1\xd9)\xd4/\xb1\xb9\xb47*.L\xbfY.\x0cJ\xd3\xb6\x8a\x1a\x8b\xe5\xd2C\xc1\x98\xed1\x9a\xdd\xc7\xc0\x8c\xb97\x82\xbf|\xae\xe4\x9462+\x99\x06\x10\x0c\x8fv\xaa\x8a\x82\xcb\x02@0m\xe5\xbdkZ\x99\xa5T\x88#\xcd.C*2\xf5\xa4\x1e!\xc9\xeeu\xd3\x98\x9aI\xc3\xf6\xce2\x96V\xac\xec\x16\xfb\xd7[\xecQ\xf9C\xf9&k\x8e\x94\xf4\x07\xcb\xf5 \xedn\x07}\xea\xc3l\xde\x97\xd7\x15\xb5\\\xc9>\xa7B\x15\xe3\xaa\x16\xf0\xab&\xefx\xa6\x95\x10[\xc5\x05\xd9\xb4\x83\'\xadY\xad\xcc\xdct\x9e\x037\xc6MY\xe0e\xa6\x8a\xe6\\\x16\x8b+\xd3\x82\xb6_/4\xfb\xb6v\xaad\xb1TBpYP\xfcy\x01\x04{v\x1c6R21UE\xb1\x15\x00h\xb5f\x82\xb6\x83!\xa7\x1fd \x0bZ<\xa6\x87\xc9\xdb\xb6fy\x89=\x98r\xcb\xf8\xbbd\xa64\x9b1\xd9\x80\x0e-\x1c\xbc+\x98\xb6\x84A\x06\xc3\x10\x96QT\x10H\xfa\xa6\x87\x07\x04G\x06:\xe8\x01\'\xe6\xb8\x04\x1cCH$\x90cq\xaa\x16\x7f\x88\xb1\xf0/0=\xa4\xdc\xe0\xe2IJ0\xf4b\xc9\x06\x86B\x8c\x06\x86\xd8D\xffP"6\xb1\xa5Gv!\xcc(\xe0b\xa4\xb9\xa6*\xc4d\x04\xec"\x9c2\x846E\xf7\x0cDiXK\xc2/\x1c\x90\x9a\x9e\x8e\xaf\x10\xca\x0ef\xddh\x0c\xd0La \xc7t;\xc4U\xaa\x1ct`})\xc1%j\x86C\x1c\x82.\xd6\x8b\x05|\x8b\x1dg\xb7\xae15h@1\x0eC\x82!\x865!"\xc1\xc1\xa9\xab\x15\xab\x82\x9e\xabp\xd70Uz5\x02\x8aA\x8c$<\x9b0\xdd\x89A\x13\x12\xba0\xb2\x0c\xb1\x04\xde\x99\x90\xd5\x9d\xdb4\x93\xfc4\xbb`\x87bT\xa1\x1cj1\x1c\xe4\x93Q\xb7\xd1\x1f0\x0cf\xad\xa9m\xf3z \xa1Ct\xaeb\xdau\x03\xa0&\x03\xee\x183d,\x9fIw\x066VS\xcb\x8av\xa0\xb5\xd2\xc6\xfe\xe4W\xb5\xbd\xb1Eg\xb6U=\xaej\xbd\x88\x0c\xc3IgHs\xc3M*xvy\x93\xdc\xee\xdf\x9d\x1dg\xb7\xf7\xefb\xab\x94\xd8qv[\xd2BR\r\xdcc\xde$\xb768;\xbe\x7f\x9b\xf3(=\xa3\xe6\xc2\xa5!\xbd\x16\x02\xc9Af*oDc0}q\x94\xd9\xd2#\xa5\x1c\x82\xb2\xd9\x8b\xfeF\x1b\x87\xd0\xa2\x18\x021\\\x061\t\x91j\x11\xaf\x91d\xac\xb1\x8eQ\xd4\x80\x1c\x0c1\x03\xb9\xfb\xcd\xaf\xd4"\xfd\xcb\xaf\xea2\xdb\x96\x0bf6\xb3U#(\x053C\x1f\nKe\xac\x192\x96\xb7\xf4\xfd\xf7T\xde\xce\x1b!6\x96ZVL\xff\x7f\x04C\x03\xe2\xc7\xb9\xc6\x10\xd1\xb8\xe9ap\r1\xf2Pu\xb3\xf9\xd0\xe4\x10\xdf\x1e\x8fR\x93X\x8d\xcb\xdf\x870\n\xfbR#\x15\xfb>\xcaQ\x0f\xef\x8e\x85\x95\xebz\x95\xbf\x1f\x89s\xdd@:$\xa8\x99zQ\x8a\x1b\xa2\x19\'TI\xbd\xff\xf5_Y\xfb$\x8e\xcdj\xd6L\xe6L\x0f\x19\n\xc3\xde\x1e\x806\x9fo4\xadU\xe4q\xba\xc60\xdbg\x99\xcaG\x19J%!\xd5\xa3R\xef\xcdIU\xab\xd2}\x02\x15\'\x1b\xe6\x08\x06"r\x99\xe0F4\xb2A\x0b\x84\xf3D\xdaSz\xbe!^\x88\xca\xc4\xa8\x9e\x11,\x88\xad\x85\x88[l&\x17L\x91!\x04\xf2\x0c\xf7;U\xd2j%L\xc69\xc7\xf2\xa4\xd6\xecj+\xdd\xbf\xb0\xa1\x07jK\x8f[U\xf7\xa8\x0cb\xd0\xcc{a\xc8X\xfe\xb1a\xb7\xb9W\xebPQ$D\x81!D\x12\xd33o\x10Y\x93;Q}\x85\x1fkH\'v\xc2\x81\xfe\xf7<e\x05\x15C\xa5,1U\xc7\xd8\x8a\xb7wHf\x8f\xd1\xa3\x14?>\xb8 \xd0\x00\xdch\tB\x9ed\x88\x08\xd3AG\x9fM\xa5<wX\x03\xe0s`\xa0\xf3\xf5\x052\xdd\x89P\x14{\x1e\x80_`\xcb+\xb6\x11<c\x9b\x92V\xe0\xb0\x0e\xceNu\x06:{\x7f\x93!\xe8R\x97\x16\xac\xfd\xbc\xacG\xfb\xf4\xda\xb7Z\x1cg\xdb\x8f\xd3 \xe8M\xebV^\x11\xd9\xae\xef\xa7xzW\xe3qyoy\xe0-\xee\xcb\xfd\xebN\xc6d$\xca\xfeZ\x08n\xd0k\xf0\xae\x86U\xff:\xb6\xfb\x1f\\\x89\x9foFW\x8b\xba\x0b\x0e\x0f\xf8\x84\x0e\xf0\x0bd\xba\x93\xc4a\xe8\xfb\x00~\x81\xbbE\x01\x9dS\x01 d\xf7\xf7\x92\xdfC\xc2$\x8c\xdcE\'\x9bMV\xb2\xbc\x11\x1dB\xe0\xb3\xf6\xf5\x12\xd8.\x11\xbba\x98\x84\xf6\xe3\x87\xb1)dQ\xcf\x91\xa3\xd7\xc0\xf9\x0f\x15\xb9\xd8\xeb\xdf\xa9q\x12\xe2\x10\xc6\xfb=\x96\x96\xe9+\x15\x0c\xc8d\xe8%==/r]\xdf\x0b\xa3\x0f!\xa0\xae,=\x9e!\xe1\x14\xb5\xd1\xdf\r\xd7\n\xc7\xb2\x8a\xe1\x16\xa8\xdc\xf4\x01~\x99Q\xf9R\t\xab{\x80!\t.\xef\x92\xac\xaam;ldv\xf2\xe9\x0b\xda\x92\xda5\xb3\x8d\x96\x06\xc0/\xb0\x06\xbe\xa4\xcfNLk\x96/\x1f~hp\x80__\x8bu\x84CK-K\xd63\xca6i\xbbxD\xdf\\\xbe\xd1\xb4C#-\xb2\xd9\x87\xc3\xa1\x8f\xcf\xa3\x104\xf2(Tv\x01\xf0\xeb\x00Y\xb7\xc9\x90\xd4M\x80l{\xd0\xc3\xe1\xf0\x80\'\x95:\x8e\x0f\xc2\x9c\xf5\xa7?< \x10\xaa Z)k\xe2t 6\xbc\xf0M\x9bl\xd6J9{ Z\x9c\x04\xb9r\xe9\xf2,\x8e:\xf7"\x87\x07\x04\xb95\xc5 \xb7\xc5\x0b\xb3[uYKb\xfb\xdc\x9ab\xe3\r\x0f\x03\x03'
```

The content-type of my response is:
`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: are you sure it is UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: It should be but I don't know really @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem like it is.

Comment: It definitely is not character data of any type.  It is binary.  To me, it looks like executable code.  Where did it come from?

Comment: I just edited it @TimRoberts

Comment: What was the `Content-Type` in the response headers?

Comment: I just added it too @TimRoberts

Comment: Look, I'm not going to pick this information from you one piece at a time like pulling teeth.  YOU are going to have to look at the response headers you got (NOT in the browser dump) and see what is going in.  Does one of the headers say it is compressed?  It didn't look gz-compressed, but maybe you didn't show us everything.